# How do i use DocumentApp.getui() on a new doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

So i have been trying to make a script that makes a doc and then uses Document.getUi()

```
var doc = DocumentApp.create('New')
var Func = DocumentApp.getUi() //Blah blah blah
```

but when I do this it gives me an error how can i fix this.

Answer (score 2):

The error received is:

> Cannot call DocumentApp.getUi() from this context.

This is consistent with the documentation for `getUi()`:

"A script can only interact with the UI for the current instance of an open document, and only if the script is bound to the document."<sup>[ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#getUi%28%29)</sup>

Since your script has created a new document, "`doc`" it's obviously not contained in it - therefore it cannot manipulate the UI for `doc`.