# Workaround to DocumentApp.getUi() context error?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to build a basic url fetch script in Google Apps Script, but I'm having a problem with the DocumentApp.getUi() function. (note: I know this seems like a duplicate of [How do i use DocumentApp.getui() on a new doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920041/how-do-i-use-documentapp-getui-on-a-new-doc), but the answer provided didn't actually *answer* the question, and it's from 2013)

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('new_doc'); //create doc
  doc.ui = DocumentApp.getUi(); // error: 'Cannot call DocumentApp.getUi() from this context.'
  var vurl = ui.prompt('url');
  var furl = fetch(vurl);
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph(furl)
}
```

I know that I can't call it this way, as the other answer explained, but is there a workaround or alternate method I can use?  I'm the only person that will be using this.

Comment: Regarding the referred Q&A it actually answers the question: it's not possible to use getUi on a document created by a script. Add more details to your question about how are you calling your function and a description of what you expect that your script do.

Comment: There's no work around.  The problem is that when you create a new doc on the server it cannot open up a user interface on a browser that doesn't exist so there is no place to display a dialog or a sidebar.  So what did you plan do to with the Ui?

Comment: @cooper thanks for the clarification, i was under the impression that i had to create the UI *before* the doc was opened. In that case would i use an onOpen() function?

Comment: You might wish to save and close.  And then open it as you would any other doc.

Comment: onOpen will not work either as it's not possible to programatically add a script to a document. Is this script only for you or someone else will used it?

Comment: @Rubén, sorry for the long delay, i'm the only person that will be using this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you are the only one that will be using this, forget about `DocumentApp.getUi()` and add the URL directly as a literal.

Assuming that `fetch` is function defined somewhere else in your project, then

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('new_doc'); //create doc
  var furl = fetch(/** replace this with your URL */);
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph(furl)
}
```